# Error : xcrun exited with non-zero code: 4 (expo ios simulator)

Tags: expo, ios-simulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJVdD.png)

I can't start expo app in ios simulator
I searched for this error and tried everything I could, but I still can't.

I tried this ways

1. checked xcode command Line Tools (Xcode 12.2(1B2B45b))
2. tried ios simulator `Erase all contents and settings`
3. created new expo project and run
4. run this command line `expo client:install:ios`
5. created `.watchmanconfig` empty object

all didn't work!

what should i do?

Comment: delete your `.expo` directory and run `expo start` without `sudo`

Comment: @brentvatne I did and run on ios simulator but didn't work

`Error installing or running app. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/Users/choieunwoo/.expo/ios-simulator-app-cache/Exponent-2.17.4.tar.app'`

Comment: @EunChio I'm also facing same problem, any solution you found ?

Comment: deleting .expo and running again without sudo solved the problem. but make sure that you have the write read access